# Detecting a physical keyboard from a keyboard extension swift ipadOS

Tags: swift, ipad, ios-keyboard-extension

i can't seem to find any documentation on how to detect the physical keyboard connection (bluetooth) inside a keyboard extension application. Our keyboard extension is helping children suffering dyslexia how to write. I need to detect if a physical keyboard is attached so i don't show the whole virtual keyboard too. I know it's possible because only one application is doing it perfectly and it's called 'Grammarly'. The only thing i tried so far is overriding the pressesBegan function which is not called in a keyboard extension.

```
func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, 
         with event: UIPressesEvent?)
```

It must be something custom i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect physical keyboard on iOS 14 GameController SDK by using public API GCKeyboard. You just need to import GameController

```
let isKeyboardConnected = GCKeyboard.coalesced != nil
```

Comment: Wow very nice, it works! Thats why i could not find any documentation. Now i need to find how to prevent the keyboard from dismissing.  thanks

Comment: how did you implement this? this is not working for me in UIInputViewController

Comment: Just import GameController in your file

Comment: that I had done, but how it will notify about the connection establishes and disconnect?

Comment: You can check this by using our bool constant isKeyboardConnected

Comment: Do you know how to use "GCKeyboardValueChangedHandler" ?

Comment: Yes find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446369/how-to-set-up-gccontroller-valuechangehandler-properly-in-xcode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238020/discussion-between-jayesh-patel-and-bhumi).